# Is there a way to flag users who continually suggest poor edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Is there a way to flag users who continually suggest poor edits? I have reviewed about ten posts in a row where a user is just adding the `python` tag to many posts that don't even reference python in them.

I have rejected these as irrelevant tags, but is there anything more I can do? Is this just an nuisance that we have to deal with (by properly assessing suggested edits), or is this something that should be prevented?

I only have 20 reviews a day; it's a shame that I wasted 10-15 of them on the same issue.

Comment: If a certain amount of edits was rejected, they'll be banned from editing automatically. No need for _"extra flagging"_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ at what point are they banned?

Comment: You could raise a moderator flag on one of the posts they tried to edit. I'm interested to see what the moderators have to say about this. I did raise a flag at least once when I saw a series of terrible edit attempts by the same user (worse than just adding a wrong tag), and I believe it came back as "helpful".

Comment: I opened a question related to that here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278158/how-to-deal-with-tags-that-could-be-considered-redundant (it looks like we were going through the queue at the same time **:-D** ) Maybe it'll help? (dunno... small FYI kind of thing)

Comment: @BorrajaX yes, same issue. Very strange to see someone do that.

Comment: What if it was never queued due to the users rep but I had to roll it back because it was so bad?

Comment: I just realized how old this was... it would be nice if we could flag poor edits.