# How to deal with tags that could be considered redundant?

Tags: support, tags

So... I'm going through the `Suggested Edits` queue, and I see a user that when there's a question tagged `Django`, `Tornado` or `Flask`, adds the `Python` tag. Should I consider that an *Irrelevant Tags* reason to reject?

On one hand, all those services (`Django`, `Tornado`...) can only be written in Python, so it looks like a redundancy. On the other hand, without the `Python` tag, people like myself who have the `Python` tag as favorite (or followed) might end up missing those questions.

So that's the thing... I don't know how to handle that. What do you guys think? (or what's the official policy in that case? )

Possibly related: [Is there a way to flag users who continually suggest poor edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278157/is-there-a-way-to-flag-users-who-continuous-suggest-poor-edits)

### UPDATE:

I've been reviewing my *Suggested Edits* queue (re-checking that kind of *only one tag addition edits*), and it looks like the consensus is to `Approve` said edits (most of the other reviewers voted to approve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is a problem, from lots of other similar cases I have seen.

The [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag would help people like you to see the question, but [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) and [tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tornado) both narrow the topic down. I see this in questions all the time, so I don't think the tag is really irrelevant.

Consider [all ~30,000 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+angularjs) tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs). AngularJS is pretty obviously a JavaScript framework, but both tags are used to clarify the topic and draw people who have [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) on their favorites lists to the question.

Comment: There is also the other side of the argument: people want mutual exclusive tags so angularjs experts don't see regular javascript questions and vice versa. That is solved by negative searches, though.

Comment: Would another common example being `android` and `java` together? Sometimes the problem really is about android, and not necessarily a question about the java syntax or something. However, the java tag may draw a little more attention.